# Java - what is returned when two keys map to same value?

Tags: java, dictionary

In Java, I understand if two keys maps to one value , linear chaining occurs due to collision.

For Example:

```
￼    Map myMap= new HashMap();   //Lets says both of them get mapped to same bucket-A and
    myMap.put("John", "Sydney");//linear chaining has occured.
    myMap.put("Mary","Mumbai"); //{key1=John}--->[val1=Sydney]--->[val2=Mumbai]
```

So when I do:

```
myMap.get("John");   // or myMap.get("Mary")
```

What does the JVM return since bucket-A contains two values?
Does it return the ref to "chain"? Does it return "Sydney"? Or does it return "Mumbai"?

Comment: If you use Collections.newSetFromMap() it actually maps every element as a key to the same value.  There is no problem doing this as values don't need to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hashCode` of your method determines what 'bucket' (aka list, aka 'linear chain') it will be put in. The `equals` method determines which object will actually be picked from the 'bucket', in the case of collision. This is why its important to properly implement both methods on all object you intend to store in any kind of hash map.

Answer (score 5):

Linear chaining happens when your keys have the same hashcode and not when two keys map to one value.

> So when I do: myMap.get("John"); // or myMap.get("Mary")

`map.get("John")` gives you Sydney

`map.get("Mary")` gives you Mumbai

> What does the JVM return since bucket-A contains two values?

If the same bucket contains two values, then the `equals` method of the key is used to determine the correct value to return.

It is worthwhile mentioning the worst-case scenario of storing (K,V) pairs all having the same hashCode for Key. Your hashmap degrades to a linked list in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your keys are different.

First some terminology

- **key**: the first parameter in the `put`
- **value**: the second parameter in the `put`
- **entry**: an `Object` that holds both the key & the value

When you `put` into a `HashMap` the map will call `hashCode()` on the key and work out which hash bucket the entry needs to go into.  If there is something in this bucket already then a `LinkedList` is formed of entries in the bucket.

When you `get` from a `HashMap` the map will call `hashCode()` on the key and work out which hash bucket to get the entry from. If there is more than one entry in the bucket the the map will walk along the `LinkedList` until it finds an entry with a key that `equals()` the key supplied.

A map will always return the `Object` tied to that key, the value from the entry. Map performance degrades rapidly if `hashCode()` returns the same (or similar) values for different keys.

You need to use java generics, so your code should really read

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This will tell the map that you want it to store `String` keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the Map first resolves the correct bucket (identified by the hashcode of the key).  If there's more than one key in the same bucket, the equals method is used to find the right value in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example what confuses you is that you think values are chained for a given key. In fact [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects are chained for a given hashcode. The hashCode of the key gives you the bucked, then you look at the chained entries to find the one with the equal key.